# How to set default environment variables for docker-compose services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Consider the example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV var=hello

ENTRYPOINT ["printenv"]
```

This container has an environment variable with a default value, which I can override:

```
docker build -t exp .
docker run exp

...
var=hello
...

docker run -e var=lalala exp

...
var=lalala
...
```

I would like to have this *optional* overridability when I use the image with docker-compose. So far I tried the following three approaches:

## Obligatory override - otherwise variable unset

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  hello-teller:
    image: exp:latest
    environment:
      - var
```

result:

```
docker-compose up
```

> `var` is not set, default value ignored.

```
env var=lala docker-compose up
```

> `var` is overridden.

## Cast in stone

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  hello-teller:
    image: exp:latest
    environment:
      - var=lala
```

result:

```
docker-compose up
```

> `var` is overridden to `lala`.

```
env var=huhu docker-compose up
```

> `var` is still overridden to `lala`.

## No effect

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  hello-teller:
    image: exp:latest
    environment:
      - ${var:-lala}
```

result:

```
docker-compose up
```

> `var` is not overridden.

```
env var=huhu docker-compose up
```

> `var` is not overridden.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files), this is possible with the 2.1 file format:

> Both $VARIABLE and ${VARIABLE} syntax are supported. Additionally when
> using the 2.1 file format, it is possible to provide inline default
> values using typical shell syntax:
>
> ${VARIABLE:-default} evaluates to default if VARIABLE is unset or
> empty in the environment. ${VARIABLE-default} evaluates to default
> only if VARIABLE is unset in the environment.

So `${var:-lala}` as you've shown in the question, is the way to go, but you appear to be missing the left side. The full line should be:

```
- var=${var:-lala}
```

I tested the syntax in my environment and it works. To use your example, I would override the variable in one of two ways:

*1) Export the variable to the environment, e.g.*

```bash
export var=happy
sudo -E docker-compose up
```

*2) Pass the environment variable directly*

```bash
var=kind sudo -E docker-compose up
```

Note that I use the `-E` option with `sudo` to preserve existing environment variables. This is very easy to forget if one has an alias like `alias docker-compose='sudo docker-compose'`.

One option is to fix that alias, or my personal preference: `alias sudo='sudo -E'`.

By the way, option 2 is my preference if running `docker-compose` over SSH.

**Using the env file**

Another option is to use an [env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/):

> Values present in the environment at runtime always override those
> defined inside the .env file. Similarly, values passed via
> command-line arguments take precedence as well.